# WebSphere 7 Shared libraries at deploy

Tags: websphere, libraries, shared

I use WebSphere 7 and I've set shared libraries as described in this example http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/06062009015816PMWEBP3Y.htm

My application is running with this setting, but I can't deploy it (update). At deploy it can't find the classes in the shared libraries. I don't have the error message right now because I had to revert the changes but maybe somebody knows what's missing from the example.

We edited the setupCmdLine.bat file and appended the path where our jars can be found to the classpath variables but i'm sure this is not the right way to do it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that ejbdeploy is the cause of the problem?  In an ND environment, ejbdeploy occurs on the dmgr as part of the installation, so using an application server shared library wouldn't make sense.  For consistency, the same is true for a standalone server.  You'll need to use the -deployejb.classpath option to AdminApp to point to your shared library classpath (in ND, the paths must exist on the dmgr).  If you're deploying from the admin console, I believe there's an "extra classpath" field you can populate.

Comment: I've found this based on your answer:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/urun_rapp_ejbdeploy.html
So I have to configure the classpath at every deploy and type (paste) all the jar-s? Can't define an ext lib where WAS could find my jars?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, you have to copy/paste if you want to use the admin console.  Alternatively, you could use scripting.  It's possible there's another option, but I'm not aware of one.